# Save as Parquet file in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet

I'm new to Spark. I'm trying save a csv file as parquet using spark java in local mode (windows). I got this error.

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows

I referred other threads and disabled spark speculation

set("spark.speculation", "false")

I still get the error. I m using only two columns in csv for testing purpose still land in this issue.

input :

```
portfolio_id;portfolio_code
1000042;CHNTESTPF04
1000042;CHNTESTPF04
1000042;CHNTESTPF04
1000042;CHNTESTPF04
1000042;CHNTESTPF04
1000042;CHNTESTPF04
1000042;CHNTESTPF04
```

My code :

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> rowJavaRDD = pairRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, Integer, String>() {
    private Double[] splitStringtoDoubles(String s){
       String[] splitVals = s.split(";");
       Double[] vals = new Double[splitVals.length];
       for(int i= 0; i < splitVals.length; i++){
           vals[i] = Double.parseDouble(splitVals[i]);
       }
       return vals;
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple2<Integer, String> call(String arg0) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
});


SQLContext SQLContext;
SQLContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);

Dataset<Row> fundDF = SQLContext.createDataFrame(rowJavaRDD.values(), funds.class);
fundDF.printSchema();

fundDF.write().parquet("C:/test");
```

Kindly help what I'm missing here.

Comment: Put the full error and stack trace in your question, please.

Comment: I got the error resolved by adding the split of function in Tuple2() like this :public void run(String t, String u){

 public Tuple2<String,String> call(String rec) {

         String[] tokens = rec.split(";");
         String[] vals = new String[tokens.length];
         for(int i= 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
       vals[i] =tokens[i];
      }
         return new Tuple2<String, String>(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
     } });

Comment: @Ans8 please put you solution in an answer and accept it, so it disappears from the "unanswered" section.

Answer (score 2):

Please find my Java/Spark code for
1) loading CSV indo Spark Dataset
2) saving Dataset to parquet

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                    .builder()
                    .appName("csv2parquet")
                    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/file:/tmp")
                    .master("local")
                    .getOrCreate();

final String dir = "test.csv";


Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).csv(dir);

final String parquetFile = "test.parquet";
final String codec = "parquet";

ds.write().format(codec).save(parquetFile);

spark.stop();
```

add this to your pom

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering here , so it goes off from unanswered section as told by @Glennie Helles Sindholt. Sorry for the delay in posting this

I got the error resolved by adding the split of function in Tuple2() like this :

```
    public void run(String t, String u)

    { 

     public Tuple2<String,String> call(String rec){ 
        String[] tokens = rec.split(";"); 
        String[] vals = new String[tokens.length]; 
        for(int i= 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
       { 
            vals[i] =tokens[i]; 
        } 

      return new Tuple2<String, String>(tokens[0], tokens[1]); 

     } 
   });
```